# Filters add inappropriate tags to audit questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-audits, filtering

When reviewing the close vote queue for a specific tag, audit questions get tagged with that tag, even if they're originally not tagged with it, and even though the tag is unrelated.

Take the following example audit question *(please don't complete it, else it will stop working for other users)*:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/17972799

Now, add a random tag to your close filter (e.g. [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)), and go to the audit again. It is now tagged with that specific tag.

These inappropriate tags mainly make me want to edit the question, and remove the tag, making me spot it's an audit as soon as I visit the question. But I could imagine that for some audits, I might close *Unclear what you're asking* or *Too broad*, since in the context of that tag, the question is unclear or unspecific (e.g. SQL questions tagged with 2 different RDBMSes, one added because of this feature).

Please, remove the tag adding from audits. Either filter audits too if audits are available for the filtered tags, or don't add a random tag from the filter. Currently, it's making audits even more confusing.

Comment: Have you ever *actually* failed an audit because of this, or it is purely a hypothetical?  Remember, the audits are designed to be approximate, it doesn't expect every one to be perfect.

Comment: @Servy No, but I did spend a lot of time the first time I saw this figuring out how the tags were related to the question, then attempting to edit the question. The main thing is that I think this feature does more harm than good.

Comment: And all of the people that spent a bunch of time being confused at why posts didn't have the filtered tag, or who saw people using the lack of the tag to avoid actually evaluating the post, thought the opposite.

Comment: I don't think the people who tend to fail audits will notice.

Comment: My point is: one reviewer might spend a lot of time trying to figure out how a C question is related to Python. Another might  think: I don't know anything about this, skip.  Or one might think: this question should be closed, it's not at all related to Python. None of these are having a normal audit experience, and are reviewing this question as they would others. The only benefit I see is avoiding people thinking the filters don't work